# jQuery switching between two elements and change the SELECT field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<div class="r_row">
<div class="row field_currency">
    <div class="f_row"><label class="" for="currency">Currency</label></div>
    <div class="r_row"> 
    <select id="currency" name="currency" class=" select">
<option value="ron" >USD</option>
<option value="eur" selected="selected">EUR</option>
</select>
        <div class="error context" id="error_currency"></div>
    <div class="hint context" id="hint_currency"></div>
    <span class="checked">&nbsp;</span>
    <div class="fancy_select"><div class="first" value="USD">USD</div><div   class=" last" value="eur">EUR</div>
<br clear="all">
</div></div>

    <br style="clear:both">
    </div>

</code></pre>
```

I want to use two divs `<div>USD</div><div>EUR</div>` , and with the help of jQuery , if i click on USD i want to change also the value of the Select box, and add a custom class to the USD div, if i clik on EUR , change the value of the select to EUR, remove the class from USD and add that class to EUR.
How can I do that ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('.first').click(function(){
         $('.first').addClass('className');
         $('.last').removeClass('className');
         $('option[value=ron]').prop("selected", true);
     });
     $('.last').click(function(){
         $('.last').addClass('className');
         $('.first').removeClass('className');
         $('option[value=eur]').prop("selected", true);
     });
});
</script>
```

Comment: So simple, so easy ,so clean, Thank you.